# How to run a SQL command with python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I would like to connect to MS SQL Server and execute a SQL command with python. I am familiar with using SQLAlchemy to create SQL tables, pandas DataFrames, etc., but how can I execute the SQL in a .sql file with python/pandas/SQLAlchemy? Is there a better way to do it?

For example I have the file 'update.sql' that contains the SQL text:

```
truncate table dev.dbo.jobs
truncate table dev.dbo.workers
go
insert into dev.dbo.jobs select * from test.dbo.jobs
insert into dev.dbo.workers select * from test.dbo.workers
```

Comment: Answered already - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725862/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-python

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQLAlchemy's connection.execute to run raw SQL queries. If you have the sql statements stored in a file then it might look something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

engine = create_engine('urltodb')
conn = engine.connect()

with open('file.sql', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        stmt = text(l)
        conn.execute(stmt)

conn.close()
```

Comment: Do I need to close this connection or will it close itself?

Comment: If you have finished using the connection, it would be best to close it in order to release it to the pool. I'll update the example.