# Django app hosting on Azure

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Django sample app and want to host it as Azure app service. I have followed some articles but not got success with anyone. Is there step by step documentation to do so or can anyone help me out in this?

I have created an app service on Azure
Connected it with ftp
There was a single file named hostingstart.html inside wwwroot
I have copied the sample app in the wwwroot folder but unable to browse the app, the azure app link showing the default page

Comment: probably wsgi configuration problem did you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/python-django-web-app

Comment: We do not want to host it on VM

Comment: in that case you need to run python project manually and allow the hosted port else serve the application using apache server

Comment: You may refer this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/08/25/deploying-django-app-to-azure-app-services-using-git-and-new-version-of-python/

Comment: Hi,any progress now?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to my work steps and check if you missed something.

***Step 1:*** Follow the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python) to create your azure python web app.

***Step 2:*** Add Python extension.

[image]

***Step 3:*** Add `web.config` file and deploy your web app.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<your project name>.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***Step 4:*** Install `pip plugin` in your `python extension environment`.

***Step 5:*** Install `django` module and other modules you want to use.

Above two steps please refer to my previous case:[pyodbc on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087407/pyodbc-on-azure/49105747#49105747)

Hope it helps you.