# Django deployment on Azure web app Windows

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service

I had a Django web app (Python 2.7) project working and running on Azure App services.

I upgraded the Python to Python 3.6 (64 bit), after making sure the project is working on my local host, I deployed it to Azure.

After deployment I am getting this error:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

Searched the internet and I installed the Python 3.6 extension.

In the log streamer I can see that the error is:

`"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'"`

I compared the new deployment to my old one and the only difference I can see is that in the new deployment, I can't see the virtual env.

Do I need to install the virtual env by myself? and if so, what will happen when I will updated my project and add libraries every time I will to do it manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you provided: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`, it seems you have issue with module package installing. You could refer to my work steps and check if you missed something.

***Step 1:*** Follow the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python) to create your azure python web app.

***Step 2:*** Add Python extension.

Of course,you could choose your desired version.

[image]

***Step 3:*** Add `web.config` file and deploy your web app.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<your project name>.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***Step 4:*** Install `pip plugin` in your `python extension environment`.

Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands cd Python361x64 and touch get-pip.py and copy the content of the url https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py into the get-pip.py via Edit button, then run python get-pip.py to install the pip tool.

***Step 5:*** Install `django` module and other modules you want to use.

Above two steps please refer to my previous case:[pyodbc on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087407/pyodbc-on-azure/49105747#49105747)

---

Just for summary here, it is sorted out by changing the `<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<your project name>.wsgi.application"/>` to `django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()`.

Comment: I sorted it out , one comment , i had to change the   <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<your project name>.wsgi.application"/> to django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application() and that solved the last issue i had

Comment: @NirElbaz Great, it summarized the solution in my answer. If you don't mind, you could mark it for answer for others' reference on the forum.

Comment: @NirElbaz If you don't mind,you could mark the answer to end this case.Thanks a lot.