# Connect to Azure analysis services from python

Tags: python, olap, azure-analysis-services

I have Azure analysis service instance, with a tabular model, I need to query the data by DAX or MDX from a python script.

I got a connection string from Azure that look's like this:

```
Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://eastus.asazure.windows.net/mymodel;Initial Catalog=mycatalog;User ID=myuser@mail.com;Password=mypass;Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate
```

I tried to connect to that connection string with `pyodbc`:

```
import pyodbc

connection_str = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://eastus.asazure.windows.net/mymodel;" \
                 "Initial Catalog=mycatalog;User ID=myuser@mail.com;Password=mypass;" \
                 "Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate"

my_connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_str)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/workspace/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    my_connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_str)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It is an OLEDB driver not ODBC. Maybe try https://pypi.org/project/pyoledb/ ?

Comment: It's seems like this library not exist anymore: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyoledb`

Comment: Was there any resolution ? Were you able to connect python with azure AS.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't found any library or interface, we created a rest interface with C# that pass the DAX requests to the Analysis Services and returns the results as JSON.

Comment: @ItzikFriedland i have a similar requirement. Even after two years i am unable to find a way in python to connect Azure Analysis services. Can you please share the abstract of your C# code.

Comment: @JaiPrakash, unfortunately, I didn't write the C# code, but the idea was to expose GET request that received DAX statement and return the relevant result based on that

Answer (score 3):

From this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33727190/1198321

It seems that the `adodbapi` library supports connecting to OLEDB.