# Establish connection to Azure Analysis Services thru service principal using "adodbapi" Python library

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-analysis-services, adodbapi

I am trying to connect to Azure Analysis Service in Python using **adodbapi**. Using Application Service Principal.

While I am able to connect and execute with my personal credentials, thru multi factor authentication. But, i am struck on how to establish connection thru Service Principal using **adodbapi**

Below code is for reference which i am trying after reading few articles. But, nothing working out.

Can someone pls help ??

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import adodbapi as aasapi
   
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    # Retrieve the IDs and secret to use with ServicePrincipalCredentials
    subscription_id = "xxxxx"
    tenant = "xxxx"
    client = "xxxx"
    client_sec = "xxxx"

    credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant, client_id=client, client_secret=client_sec)

    aasConn = aasapi.connect("Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://<xxxx>.asazure.windows.net/<server>;Catalog=<TabularDatabase>;UID=;PWD={0}".format(credential))
```

Comment: You can refer to [Connect to Azure analysis services from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784236/connect-to-azure-analysis-services-from-python) and [answer by Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33727190/15969115)

Comment: Did this with MSAL by acquiring Token and passing only the token as the `password`
Slighty differnet usecase though