# Connecting to a SQL Server data base in Jupyter using unixODBC

Tags: python, jupyter, pyodbc, unixodbc

When trying to connect to the server/database I'm getting this error:

> [Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
>   'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")]

In the company where I work, Python runs on a Unix computer that we connect to.  The database server I'm trying to connect to is a Microsoft SQL Server RDBMS.

My end goal is to manipulate the data using Python in Jupyter notebook.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to Microsoft SQL server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725862/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-python)

Comment: It sounds like you simply haven't installed an ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: @GordThompson I assume the ODBS Driver for SQL Server should be installed on the Linux computer that Python runs on and not on my personal computer, correct?  This is what pyodbc.drivers() returned: 'AmazonRedshift',
 'Hive',
 'Impala',
 'Oracle',
 'PostgreSQL',
 'Salesforce',
 'SQLServer',
 'Teradata'

Comment: **(1)** Yes, the ODBC driver needs to be installed on the machine that will be running the Python code. **(2)** Based on the `pyodbc.drivers()` list, try `DRIVER=SQLServer` and see if that works.