# Connect Django to Azure Analysis Services

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks, azure-analysis-services

I am fairly new to all of his so would appreciate the help. Does anyone knows how would  you "connect" to Azure Analysis Services with Django to use as data source?
I am assuming within settings.py you would need to change database.
Default is SQL lite:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

I am looking at [Connecting to Microsoft SQL server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725862/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-python/33727190#33727190) so would it be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, you cannot connect Django to Azure Analysis Services.

**Reference:**  [Data sources supported in Azure Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource)

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/556165-azure-analysis-services

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure