# is pytds the only way to connect with TLS to Microsoft SQL Server using python?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, ssl

according to [pytds connect documentation](https://python-tds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytds.html#pytds.connect) we have a way to provide here path to cafile to enable TLS when connecting to Microsoft SQL server. good.

I am not python specialist, what are the other ways to enable TLS using other python database drivers ?

pyodbc, (would it be located on the odbc driver config level) ?

adodbapi...

on windows the certificates are automatically found in repository, it's not the case on unix

the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725862/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-python/33787509) are not complete enough concerning TLS in the connection string

(the finality is to use [Robotframework-Database-Library](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/1.2.2/DatabaseLibrary.html#Connect%20To%20Database%20Using%20Custom%20Params)  to connect to MSSQL enabling only TLS v1.2 connection)

thanks

Comment: *On windows the certificates are automatically found in repository* Only if you've already added them to Trusted Roots. SQL Server certificates are self-signed by default.

Comment: Have you looked into using pyodbc with "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"? Microsoft documentation walks you through using it from Windows, linux and macOS, [including TLS-capable examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connection-string-keywords-and-data-source-names-dsns#using-tlsssl) using options `Encrypt=yes` with `TrustServerCertificate=no` (for certs in your cert store) and `TrustServerCertificate=yes` (for self-signed certs not in your cert store).